# Chrome Extension XHR receives 403 response except when initiated from file:///

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-status-code-403

I'm developing a Chrome Extension that utilizes the [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) API for currency exchange rates.

I develop the extension through a simple HTML page where I include my JavaScript via `<script>` tags. When I want to test it live, I build it, go to `chrome://extensions` and click *Load unpacked extension*.

Whenever I make requests to the API from my simple HTML development page, everything works fine. However, when I build my extension and make a request through a content script, I receive a 403 response from the API.

Right off the bat, I'm going to say that I have these permissions in my manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
  "https://*/*",
  "http://*/*"
]
```

Here's how I load my script (as requested by Makyen):

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "css": [
      "main.css"
    ],
    "js": [
      "script.js"
    ],
    "matches": [
      "file:///*",
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  }
]
```

And if I change the request to another (dummy) API:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?base=USD
```

Everything works everywhere, so that means the problem is not in my extension settings.

The problematic request is this:

```
https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD
```

And it gives the error:

```
GET https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD 403 (Forbidden)
```

Here's the code that initializes the request:

```
function currencyAPICall(currency, callback) {
    var url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=" + currency,
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.addEventListener("load", function () {
        callback(data.rates);
    });

    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);

    return req;
}
```

---

To test this, I let my extension run on file URLs while in my development HTML file. I.E. the same code runs twice, once from my HTML page, once from the extension. Here are the results:

[image: comparing file and localhost requests from extension and script]

My extension receives a 403 everywhere except when using the `file` protocol. Doesn't matter if it runs on localhost, StackOverflow, even the fixer.io website itself. The request uses `https`.

### Summation

Extension content script receives a 403 response from an API call everywhere except when run on a page with the `file` protocol, even with the right manifest permissions. **Why?**

If I make a request to another URL (the aforementioned dummy API), I don't get this error. Does that mean the problem is in the fixer.io server? Or I need to set some sort of header?

I also wrote an [issue](https://github.com/hakanensari/fixer-io/issues/79) about this on fixer.io's GitHub repo.

**Edit:**

One of the main differences I noticed is the `Origin` and `Referer` headers. The response seems to be 200 if either both of them are set or both of them are not. When I receive the 403 response, `Referer` is set, but `Origin` isn't.

**Edit:**

As suggested by PredatorIWD, making the request from an [Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (aka Background Page) doesn't result in a 403. I get a normal 200 OK response.

Comment: If you are sending the request from your extensions HTML file then you need to add that to `web_accessible_resources`. Its usually also better to send requests from the `background.js` and use messaging to send the required data back to the content script. Also the origin header is added by the browser automatically and can't be controlled by the user.

Comment: `web_accessible_resources` doesn't do anything in that case, because "Content scripts themselves do not need to be whitelisted." However, making the request in an Event (Background) Page doesn't result in a 403. I might just change my code around to utilize that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You've left key information out of your question. Chrome extensions run code in multiple different contexts. We need to see how you are loading your code. Thus, a manifest.json showing content and background script entries (`permissions`, `browser_action`/`page_action`) and as much of the code from your various different scripts and HTML to provide us with a *complete*, but minimal, MCVE which duplicates the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not having any code problems whatsoever. My code works perfectly. I have a networking problem that is probably related to protocols, for which I gave plenty of information. I have a content script (I mentioned it) that makes an AJAX request which sometimes results in 403. I gave the `permissions` because related problems are often caused by them. I pointed out that I've set them correctly. Why give the whole manifest? Could the name of my extension be causing the problem?

Comment: I updated my question. Besides, it's the **server** that seems to be causing the problem. And I have no control over it. I gave information about when the problem occurs and when it doesn't, which I'm pretty sure is all I can possibly give in this situation. I'm not asking anyone to "fix my code". I was hoping to get an idea for a different _approach_ to my problem so that I can _program_ my application in a way that works. Thankfully, @PredatorIWD helped in exactly that way.

Comment: @PredatorIWD you should write that comment as an answer so that I can mark it as correct. I ended up moving my request in an Event Page and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, it's usually better to send requests from the `background.js` and use messaging to send the required data back to the content script.

Heres is an example of a simple one-time messages from the background script to the content script:

From the background script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell);
    });
});
```

To the content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello"){
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    }
});
```

You can read more about message passing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).